# unable to open Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, unix, gimp, eps, ubuntu-20.04

I have many .eps files in a folder . I just want them to see how it looks. So i tried to open .eps file using document viewer it doesnot open.  Again i tried through `gv file.eps`  still it gives error like undefined Obj.....again when i tried to open through `gimp file.eps` there is also some problem like opening failed: Could not interpret PostScript file. I donot know why such types of problem exist in ubuntu 20.04(may be library problem). If it is required to install some extra packages let me know. I hope some solutions from experts side. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your question would be a better fit for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Belongs on a Linux or Unix site.

Comment: I suspect your .eps file(s) are not Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) programs but without seeing one I can't tell for certain. Make a file available and I'll look at it.